# Change name of 3D section in Product

Tags: vb.net

I've got a Product in CATIA containing several CATParts.
I use the symbol Sectioning in DMU Review Creation to create a section, to cut the product.
This section is called Section.1.

What I'm looking for is a code to take the name from CATPart 1 ( myPartNumber1) and change the name of the section from "section.1" into myPartNumber1.

This is my code so far in vb.NET:

```
Sub x()

Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

myPartNumber1 = productNumber1.Product.Products.Item(1).Name
Set selection1 = productDocument1.Selection
selection1.Search("Name='Section.1',all")
selection1.item(1).value.Name = myPartNumber1

End Sub
```

I get a problem in the last line.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code directly instead of inserting a picture... StackOverflow can format & highlight your code. What is the exact problem you have ? What is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Sub CATMain()

```
Set oprod = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product
Set TheSections = oprod.GetTechnologicalObject("Sections")
Set mySection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product.GetTechnologicalObject("Sections")

Set oSection = oprod.GetTechnologicalObject("Sections")
Set selectionpart = CATIA.ActiveDocument.selection

partcount = selectionpart.Count
    for k = 1 to partcount
            Set selectionpart = oprod.Products.Item(k)
    myPartNumber = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product.Products.Item(k).Name

    sectioncount = oSection.Count
    MsgBox sectioncount
            for i = 1 To sectioncount 
                Set oSection = mySection.item(i)
                oSection.Name = myPartnumber
        Next
    Next
```

End Sub

PROBLEM:
What I get is that all of my Sections get the name of the first Part in Product

What I need ist: first section gets the name of the first PArt, second sections gets the name of the second Part ...

I've obviously written something wrong in my loops.

THX